# Is it safe to keep an application Context and use it for Toast and SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, applicationcontext

1. How I get a Application Context:

   ```
   private static OBDApplication mInstance;

   public static OBDApplication getInstance () {
       return mInstance;
   }
   @Override
   public void onCreate () {
       super.onCreate();
       mInstance = this;
   }
   ```
2. I know that application Context can't be used everywhere, for example, `Dialog` and `startActivity`. And I know, I should always let the reference  with activity Conetxt finish when activity destroyed. But I notice that,`Toast` and `SharedPreferences` can use application Context, and it seems to be very innocent that would not lead to a memory leak.
3. So what am I suppose to do? If the problems above does not exist, then things can be cool:

   ```
   public static void toast ( @StringRes int resID){
       Toast.makeText(OBDApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), resID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```
4. But I know easiest way, so I took some time to search but I get some opposite opinions.

   Someone said: *"it's bad to use application Context, cause while activity destroy, the toast of this activity should release too, but if u use application Context which means it's life is as long as the application. So is kind of waste"*.

   However, someone said: *"it's good to use application Context, cause in this case, you always use a same object , a same toast ,that means it will not produce new toast again and again"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely you can use application context for show toast and sharedprefrence also , Because they both are use without interact with activity.

Simple example is like service, you can use both of this from service and service have no any activity reference but it's working fine..

Comment: :) emm,I still confused it's good or ' bad to use applicationContext for make a toast,i am not talk about the conveniences.i am concern about performance,u know , is it will produce waste?like i said above,at list 4.If there is not definite an answer ,may be i will make a rule in my project:1)in the activity,toast should use activity context 2)in other place ,may be use application context is not a big thing

Comment: it's good and  no any reason for said that bad. cause of `applicationContext` is give us application reference that is use in sharedpreference and toast also.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Application Context` Throught Application even in

`Activity` and `Service` mean you can use in all Android Components .

Also Showing `Toast` messages , `SharedPreferences` , Catering `DataBase` Object ,`LayoutInflater` .

> Application – is a singleton instance running in your application
>   process.  It can be accessed via methods like getApplication() from an
>   Activity or Service, and getApplicationContext() from any other object
>   that inherits from Context.  Regardless of where or how it is
>   accessed, you will always receive the same instance from within your
>   process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Toast and shared preferences doesn't having parent view of the application, it will accept all the application context and it will not demand for the application context of your application. it will work even if your application is not in active.

whereas , in our application we may create some view which will run only in our application context. when you save it in static and try to use when that particular context is not exist, it will trough an exception.

So, the save border is , We should not save the instances of our application context anywhere. you should retrieve it when you need it from your application using `getActivity()` from fragment, `this` from Activity.

Comment: 1)wow,yes u remind me,once i click a button that will make toast many times and then i kill the app,but the toasts still show for a long time.your word explain it.

Comment: Accept my answer if its helpful

Comment: 2)and u said the border,i get it.I will be very careful when i do that.But now i let my eye small focus on TOAST,and i don't keep a applicationContext while i keep a instance of application(i know is singleton),is it safe?Frankly,i feel so safe so warm cause if the app crash and restart ,the instance of application will be created ,so the static reference will point to the instance,so still work

Comment: So, You plan to use the context with the static context . right?

Comment: no,i will not use any static context to keep a `applicationInstance.getApplicationContext()`;i am not a careless guy;|) .oh  relax,i just what to use it in `Toast.makeText(OBDApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),resID,Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show(); `.  Indeed,after use leakcanary,i am sensitive about Context.hahhaha